# Method that should give me indexes doesn't compile

Tags: java, indexing

Here's the problem, I made method that gives me index of the biggest digit from file, but it doesn't compile and I can't resolve that problem, is everything alright with my code?
Is there a problem with an array or largestDigit? I can't get it at all.

```
public class TableBuilder {//CLASS CONTAINS METHODS
    public static Scanner scanner;
    public final static String filePath = "C:\\Temp\\tab.txt";
    public static int[] table;
    public static File file;
    public static int largestDigit;

    public static File makeNewFile() {
        file = new File(filePath);
        return file;
    }

    public static void openFile() {
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        }
    }

    public static void exitFile(File file) {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static int[] buildTable() throws IOException {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.print(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        int tableLength = (int) file.length();
        table = new int[tableLength];
        return table;
    }

    public static void findLargestDigit() throws IOException {
        int digit;
        largestDigit = 0;
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            digit = scanner.nextInt();
            if(digit>largestDigit) {
                largestDigit = digit;
                System.out.println("\n"+largestDigit);
            }
        }
    }

public static void findIndexOfLargestDigit() throws IOException {
        int largestIndex = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<table.length; i++) {
            if(table[i]<table[largestIndex]) {
                largestIndex = i;
                System.out.print(table[largestIndex]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              TableBuilder.makeNewFile();
        TableBuilder.openFile();
        TableBuilder.buildTable();
        TableBuilder.makeNewFile();
        TableBuilder.openFile();
        TableBuilder.findLargestDigit();
        TableBuilder.findIndexOfLargestDigit();
    }
}
```

My program gives that result:

```
1 5 5 3 -1 2 5 4
5
```

BUT it also should give indexes of largest digit from file in the last line!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't compile"? Can you please post the compilation error?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: It's very strange that the program doesn't compile, yet it gives a result? So, what's it, doesn't it compile (and in that case, what's the error you're having?) or doesn't it work?

Comment: I meant that method findLargestDigit() doesn't give any result but it should because code is written allright.

Comment: @jas97 Obviously your code is not right when you do not get the expected result

Comment: It does give a result: "\n5". Also your code won't work if al digits are negative.
Have you stepped trough your code with a debugger and some breakpoints?

Comment: A lot of things are wrong with you code. your `findLargestDigit` method works with the scanner. but your `findIndexOfLargestDigit` method works with a table. And this table is empty because your `buildTable` method is completely wrong.

Comment: Proper usage of concepts and terms is critical in IT: compiling is the step where source code gets transformed into some machine usable form. If the code is syntactically correct it will compile, but it may give wrong results, or crash, but these are totally different things.

Comment: Your `buildTable()` method just creates an empty array, That array is never filled. Thus your `findIndexOfLargestDigit()` method will never work as it uses that array, that will always be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the method 'findIndexOfLargestDigit'

```
//It prints all the indices of the largest digit

public static void findIndexOfLargestDigit() throws IOException {
    int largestIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
        if(table[i]==largestDigit) {
            largestIndex = i;
            System.out.print(largestIndex);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `findIndexOfLargestDigit()` method doesn't print anything because your `buildTable` only creates an empty array. `table = new int[tableLength];` only creates an `int` array with a length of `tableLength` filled with `0`s. This array is never filled anywhere in the code.

Apart from that, I can see several errors in your code:

- `File.length()` returns the size, in bytes, of the File, which may not coincide with the number of digits written on the File.
- Your `findLargestDigit()` method works with the scanner while your `findIndexOfLargestDigit()` works with the array. This is not very coherent.
- Your `findIndexOfLargestDigit()` doesn't print the indexes where the largest element is, but all the indexes of the elements that are bigger than all the previous elements.

There is probably more of them. You need a lot of refining in that code. Also, debugging is very useful to find errors in algorithms.